# Signature verification using only a hashed/encoded message

Tags: hash, cryptography, digital-signature

Is there any way to verify the OpenSSL signature using only {signature,hashed message} pair, skipping the original file to be presented for verification?

I need to verify the signature with only {signature,hashed message} pair remotely so using the original file is cumbersome specially when its very large.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to verify the OpenSSL signature using only hash value and without needing the original file?

Yes, but there are strings attached.

The scheme which requires the original message to be presented to the verifying function is a *Signature Scheme with Appendix (SSA)*. A scheme like the old PKCS #1.0 signing is an example of it.

The scheme which does not require the original message is a *Signature Scheme with Recovery (PSSR)*. In a PSSR, the encoded message is part of the signature and masked. A scheme like the new PKCS #2.0 PSSR signing is an example of it.

There are no schemes that take just a hash, as far as I know. You have to have the {message,signature} pair. Allowing the message to be disgorged from the signing or verification can be a security violation.

OpenSSL provides both of them, as does most other security libraries, like Botan, Crypto++, NSS, etc.

Also see [RSA signature on TLS](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/99877/29925) on Information Security Stack Exchange.

---

> I have been trying to verify the signature with hash value remotely so using the original file is cumbersome specially when its very large.

That's the insecure thing signature schemes want to avoid....

Comment: Thanks @jww for the answer. I meant that I need to do verification using only {signature,hashed message} pair (updated the question now). I understood that Signature Scheme with Recovery (PSSR) should be used to achieve this. Do you know how to generate PKCS signatures in OpenSSL and similarly perform verification over it? Thanks